# In ionic inAppBrowser I want custom close button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser, ionic-native

In ionic InAppBrowser, I want a custom close button after loading the webpage.

After closing the browser with that custom button it should give toast in the app with message 'Thank You For Visiting Our Website'.

`const browser = this.iab.create('exampleurl.com', '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button close can be only modified in the native part of the plugin.It cannot be modified in the java/html/css level.

```
browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
   //use toastcontroller
});
```